# JSR352: Monitoring Status of Job, Step and Partitions?

Tags: jsr352, java-batch

IBM's version of JSR352 provides a Rest API  which can be used to trigger jobs, restart them, get the job logs. Can it also be used to get the status of each step and each partition of the step?

I want to build a job monitoring console from where i can trigger the jobs and monitor the status of the steps and partitions in real time without actually having to look into the job log. (after i trigger the job it should periodically give me the status of the step and partitions)

How should i go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to our batch events, a JMS topic tree where we publish messages at various stages in the batch job lifecycle, (job started/ended, step checkpointed, etc.)

See the [Knowledge Center documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_batch_monitoring.html) and [this whitepaper](http://www-03.ibm.com/support/techdocs/atsmastr.nsf/WebIndex/WP102603) as well for more information.